# Stop making images on desktop bigger than original size

Tags: html

I have a image random script on folder /1
On my public_html, i have one index.html, only to show the random image script:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"><title>Document</title></head><body><img src="./1" width="100%" height="100%">
```

I have to do that, because before, on mobile devices, my images are bigger that the screen.
Now, i have problem solved on mobile devices. The images are 100% scale on screen.
But on desktop, the images are way too big.
Anyone know how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @media in CSS as per your screen size:-

```
img{
     width:50%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    img {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i dont know how to work with CSS. Where i should put that code?

Comment: Inside head tag.  Use <style> tag and write the above code in style tag and then close your style tag

Comment: Now its mutch better, thanks! But in some image, it doesnt fit 100% on index, i have to give 1 or 2 scroll on mouse. Its possible to fix that?

Comment: Then set image height

Comment: Im sorry, but i dont know CSS. Its possible to help me with small but crucial change?

Answer (score 0):

No you have to use CSS for any kind of style and it also contains of 3 type. Use as per need

```
img{
      width:50%;
 } 
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
     img {
           width:100%;
      } 
}
```

As per need this is perfect answer